# Alternative way to find out if the element is in the list

Tags: java

Is there an alternative way to check if an element is in the list without using contains() method?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `contains` method?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `list.indexOf(o) >= 0` but this is just the implementation of contains() in ArrayList. Or you could iterate the list and check with equals() but then that's basically how indexOf is implemented.